# Django Query from Post

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to pass into my DRF API a post that needs to be queried against the database. For now I have included only 2 fields that can be queried. I am having trouble getting the view to work. Here is what I have so far.

**POST**

```
{
    "city": "Denver",
    "state": "CO"
}
```

**Serializer** only lets city and state be accepted

```
class EventQuerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ('city', 'state')
```

**View** note that EventsSerializer is used in the return and I can confirm it works for a basic get request

```
class QueryEvents(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request):
        serializer = EventQuerySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            events = Events.objects.get(serializer)
            return Response(EventsSerializer(events).data)
```

**Error**
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Show the full traceback please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run save on you serializer to retrieve instance:

```
# ...
if serializer.is_valid():
    event = serializer.save()
    events = Events.objects.get(pk=event.pk)
    # ...
```